# How can I make UITableViewCell stick to bottom when isEditing is enabled?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uikit

I have a `UITableViewCell` at the very bottom of `tableview`, it's functionality is to add new object to the list. But I also want the user to be able to move his objects. And here comes the problem I can not solve: how can I make this `UITableViewCell` not movable when `tableView.isEditing` is true so it is always at the bottom of section, even when user tries to move it there?

Comment: Couple options, depending on your exact needs. One would be to make your last row the table view footer instead of a row. Another would be to return `false` for `canMoveRowAt` for the last row and "reset" the positions in `moveRowAt` if destination is past the last row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example of preventing rows from being moved past the last row:

```
class ReorderViewController: UITableViewController {
    var myData = ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Don't let me move!"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let btn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .edit, target: self, action: #selector(self.startEditing(_:)))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btn
        
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    
    @objc func startEditing(_ sender: Any) {
        isEditing = !isEditing
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = myData[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // don't allow last row to move
        return indexPath.row < (myData.count - 1)
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, toProposedIndexPath proposedDestinationIndexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath {
        // if user tries to drop past last row
        if proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == myData.count - 1 {
            // send it back to original row
            return sourceIndexPath
        }
        return proposedDestinationIndexPath
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        let itemToMove = myData[sourceIndexPath.row]
        myData.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        myData.insert(itemToMove, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    }
    
}
```